# Get Attachment from ServiceNow INC via Powershell

Tags: powershell, soap, attachment, servicenow

Im trying to download an attachment from a ServiceNow Change Request via Powershell. The attachment sys_id is different from the Change Request sys_id so I am not sure how to join them. The only things I can seem to find on the matter are in Java(?maybe?) and I do not know Java nor know how to bring Java into Powershell to retrieve the data. Any help would be greatly appreciated! Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To make a REST call via PowerShell, use "Invoke-RestMethod". 
[Example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yY56k.gif)

You can also script it out. Here's the doc: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/reference/5.1/microsoft.powershell.utility/invoke-restmethod

What you want to do to get the attachment, is use the attachment API: /api/now/attachment/[attachment record sys_id].

You can get this sys_id of any attachments associated with a given record, by performing this query on the sys_attachment table:

**table_sys_id=[your record's sys_id here]**

Once you've got the sys_id of the attachment(s) you're looking for, just plug them one-by-one, into the attachment API mentioned above.

Should be no problemo to script this all out in powershell. :-)